how to step through Excel sheets in a workbook and refresh queries using VBA
I have an issue with some code, that is not behaving as I expect.
I have 2 spreadsheets, one contains code and a summary sheet and the other a series of sheets that each contain a query linking to an SQL database.
The code is intended to step through each sheet of the query spreadsheet, refresh the query, copy the sheet name and then update a sheet in the code spreadsheet, giving the name of the sheet and the time the refresh happened.
The code starts correctly, finds the first sheet, refreshes the query, switched to the other sheet, update the information and then switched back, however it does not move onto the next sheet but just keeps repeating the same sheet.
I presume the issue is that the For ... ..Next loop and the fact I switch between spreadsheet making it lose it's place and then restarting.
Any ideas how I can make this work. (Note the query spreadsheet can have new sheets added or removed each month so I cannot just work a fixed list.)
I have considered moving the summary sheet to the query sheet, but I'm not convinced that this will still not fail due to switching sheets.
Here is my code
Sub refresh_data_1()
Dim sheetname As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sc As Integer

Let curr_dir = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Let curr_dir = curr_dir & "\data\"
'
'open raw data
'
Workbooks.Open curr_dir & "query_sheet.xlsx"
Windows("query_sheet.xlsx").Activate

Let sc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
Windows("code_spreadsheet.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("refresh dates").Visible = True
Sheets("refresh dates").Select

Range("D1").Select
Let ActiveCell = sc ' record how many sheets there are
Range("b3").Select
Windows("query_sheet.xlsx").Activate
For Each ws In .ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

With ws
Let sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Windows("code_spreadsheet.xlsm").Activate
Let ActiveCell = sheetname
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
Let ActiveCell = Now()
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Activate
Windows("query_sheet.xlsx").Activate
Next

End Sub`


How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA

Using object varibles to avoid Select and Activate.

Note: Untested Code. Please feedback if the output is not your expected.
Microsoft documentation:

Application.ScreenUpdating property (Excel)


Worksheet.ListObjects property (Excel)


Range.Offset property (Excel)

Sub refresh_data_1()
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim shtCnt As Integer, oTab As ListObject
    Dim currDir As String, rCell As Range
    Dim currWK As Workbook, qryWK As Workbook
    Set currWK = ActiveWorkbook ' code_spreadsheet.xlsm
    currDir = currWK.Path & "\data\"
    'open raw data
    Set qryWK = Workbooks.Open(currDir & "query_sheet.xlsx")
    shtCnt = qryWK.Sheets.Count
    With currWK.Sheets("refresh dates")
        .Visible = True
        .Range("D1").Value = shtCnt ' record how many sheets there are
        Set rCell = .Range("B3")
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each oSht In qryWK.Worksheets
        For Each oTab In oSht.ListObjects
            oTab.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        Next
        rCell = oSht.Name
        rCell.Offset(0, 1) = Now()
        Set rCell = rCell.Offset(1)
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


